# given hash file, dumped into memory, can I find out the line number for a given field

Tags: perl, file, hash, numbers, line

For example,   I have a perl data file, hash structure :

> line 1: $VAR1 = {
>
> line 2:  k1 => v1,
>
> line 3:  k2 => {
>
> line 4:     k2.k1=>v2.v1
>
> line 5:  }
>
> ...
>
> line n: };
>
> $VAR1

Now by reading the hash file , it will be dump hash into memory and the top hash reference is > > created.

> my $VAR1 = do $hash_file;

What I see in perl code is the hash in the memory. If given $VAR1->{'k1'},  how can I get the "line 2"?

I don't see there is a reliable way to map line number with the hash structure ( or, general perl data structure).

Thanks.

Comment: What significance does the line number have? If order matters, don't use a hash, use an array (of hashes). Also, you shouldn't be using `do` like that without error checking; use `require` or `use` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it reliably with native hashes.  Perl does not guarantee the ordering of hash.  In fact, in some versions of Perl the hash ordering will be different every time you run the program.  That said, you could write a custom parser for the file you are reading in and get the line number that way.  Of course, all of this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Perhaps you should take a step back and explain why you want to do this thing.